# Can I use open-source version of Qt for commercial applications?

Tags: qt, licensing

I need to develop a pc based application for one of our clients. Inturn, that application will be distributed to others for a price.  I'll not be sharing my code with any of them. We are planning to use Qt-C++ for developing the application. So now, can I use open-source version of Qt? Or do I have to buy a license? I read the LPGL documents, but I'm still not clear. Can someone explain to me in a simple language to answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: Yes.. You can.
Even if you want to be on safer side please send a mail to that parricular application vendor amd ask a permission.